# Interactive markers does not appear on Moveit only for my custom robot

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, srdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I import the package to Moveit I cant see Interactive markers to my robot so I can't execute a motion plan. I have checked urdf with `check_urdf`, I can move all links on Moveit Setup Assistant and all looks ok. I start Rviz with roslaunch '/home/student/Desktop/robot_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch'
I export files from Moveit Setup Assistant to Desktop then I move folder to /opt/ros/indigo/share , I do `roslaunch /opt/ros/indigo/share/assem5_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch` Markers appeared one time but not again after re-export, am I doing right way?

[Screenshoots, Robot,  Moveit setup assistant.] (https://postimg.org/gallery/pcyvpyvk/)

SRDF:

```
  <robot name="Assem5.SLDASM">
    <group name="arms"><link name="link_1"/>
       <link name="link_2"/>
      <link name="link_3"/>
      <link name="link_4"/>
      <link name="link_5_tool"/>
    </group>
    <group_state name="pose_0" group="arms">
      <joint name="joint_1" value="0"/>
      <joint name="joint_2" value="0"/>
      <joint name="joint_3" value="0"/>
      <joint name="joint_4" value="0"/>
      <joint name="joint_5_tool" value="0"/>
    </group_state>
    <end_effector name="end_effector_link 5" parent_link="link_4" group="arms"/>
    <virtual_joint name="base_joint_virtual_link" type="fixed" parent_frame="world_frame" child_link="base_link"/>
```

Information when i upload it to Moveit:

```
[ INFO] [1480689682.201512724]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1480689682.201602195]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
All is well! Everyone is happy! You can start planning now!
Registered event listener change listener:  true 
[ INFO] [1480689683.789499562]: Loading robot model 'Assem5.SLDASM'...
[ WARN] [1480689683.935955978]: Could not identify parent group for end-effector 'end_effector_link 5' 
[ INFO] [1480689684.093612791]: Loading robot model 'Assem5.SLDASM'...
[ WARN] [1480689684.233352057]: Could not identify parent group for end-effector 'end_effector_link 5'
[ WARN] [1480689684.233805597]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[ INFO] [1480689684.818941731]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1480689684.826124575]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1480689685.533798626]: No active joints or end effectors found for group ''. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[ INFO] [1480689685.534217491]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'arms'. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[ WARN] [1480689685.534651803]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[ INFO] [1480689685.541682110]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'arms'. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[ INFO] [1480689685.544602709]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arms' in namespace ''
[ INFO] [1480689686.447761196]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group arms.
[ INFO] [1480689686.447874546]: Looking around: no
[ INFO] [1480689686.447957077]: Replanning: no
```

Update 1:

[Robot structure] (https://s24.postimg.org/a3zd9atid/robot_structure.jpg)

**demo.launch file:**

```
<launch>

  <!-- By default, we do not start a database (it can be large) -->
  <arg name="db" default="false" />
  <!-- Allow user to specify database location -->
  <arg name="db_path" default="$(find PR2_moveit_config_dpyralis_test_1)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" />

  <!-- By default, we are not in debug mode -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false" />

  <!-- Load the URDF, SRDF and other .yaml configuration files on the param server -->
  <include file="$(find PR2_moveit_config_dpyralis_test_1)/launch/planning_context.launch">
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <!-- If needed, broadcast static tf for robot root -->
  

  <!-- We do not have a robot connected, so publish fake joint states -->
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>

  <!-- Given the published joint states, publish tf for the robot links -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen" />

  <!-- Run the main MoveIt executable without trajectory execution (we do not have controllers configured by default) -->
  <include file="$(find PR2_moveit_config_dpyralis_test_1)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="true"/>
    <arg name="fake_execution" value="true"/>
    <arg name="info" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Run Rviz and load the default config to see the state of the move_group node -->
  <include file="$(find PR2_moveit_config_dpyralis_test_1)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- If database loading was enabled, start mongodb as well -->
  <include file="$(find PR2_moveit_config_dpyralis_test_1)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" if="$(arg db)">
    <arg name="moveit_warehouse_database_path" value="$(arg db_path)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

[Robot structure] (https://s24.postimg.org/a3zd9atid/robot_structure.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249280/interactive-markers-does-not-appear-on-moveit-only-for-my-custom-robot/) by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-07**:
Do you have a gripper in your robot? If so, it should be created as a seperate group and should be added to the end effector in the moveit dialog. What is the launch file you are using?

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-07**:
I do not have gripper/tool there is only the active links. The launch file is demo.launch I updated the question (cant mark it as code). The folder with URDF and exported package  from Moveit Setup assistant is one desktop. I tried with PR2 like on tutorial but there is no interactive marker.

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-07**:
But the official exported package on opt/ros/indigo/share/PR2_moveit_config is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't follow the moveit setup assistant tutorial properly.You have defined links for the "arms" group in setup assistant ,but you didn't define the joints for the same group. That is the reason your srdf doesn't have any joints defined in the arms group. Then you should define the kinematic solver for arms group by double clicking the name of the group in planning group dialog.

[image: image description]

Next create a seperate group for your tool joint and define the kinematic solver as none for this. Then make this group as the end effector group and the parent group of the end effector as arms group. This will resolve this warning

`No active joints or end effectors found for group 'arms'. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.`

After fixing this, run demo.launch and you can see the interactive markers. For additional information, follow the steps in this [Moveit](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html#step-4-add-planning-groups) tutorial .

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-09**:
I tried this tutorial and it is working but after I tried again and this error appeared:

```
Invalid <arg> tag: pr2_generated
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks.
```

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-09**:
Arg xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-12**:
Delete the packages and reinstall it ,then run. It might be denoting a wrong path sometimes.

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-13**:
I export package form Moveit Setup Assistant to desktop then I move it to /opt/ros/indigo/share
Then I do `roslaunch '/opt/ros/indigo/share/assem5_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch'`
Markers appeared one time but not again after re-export with same setup, am I doing right way?

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-13**:
install the package [moveit tutorials](http://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/tree/kinetic-devel/doc) in local workspace and try it. I think it will fix this issue

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-13**:
The local work space is the catkin folder or /opt/ros/indigo/share ?

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-13**:
catkin folder

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-13**:
I have never used catkin workspace just /opt/ros/indigo/share/ I hope to fix it..

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-17**:
If I install moveit tutorials in local workspace catkin_make gives errors..
It worked when I used right the planing proup on Moveit Setup Assistant and the exported package **must** be the same as the URDF package on opt/ros/indigo/share/<package_name>. But interactive markers are lagging